# SAP GUI VBA loop through cells of report variant

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

Maybe someone can give me a hint, I need to loop through the text cells of a `GuiTableControl` object in a report variant (`RSEOUT00`) until I find the next empty text cell, and there I need to fill in the content from an Excel cell.

```
Session.FindByID("wnd[1]/usr/tabs/TAB_STRIP/tabpNOSV/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3030/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE_E/txtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_[1,0]").text <> ""
```

How can I increment in `/txtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_[1,0]").text` the 0 and do something on the empty line found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example:

. . .

i = i + 1

Session.FindByID("wnd[1]/usr/tabs/TAB_STRIP/tabpNOSV/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3030/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE_E/txtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_[1," & cstr(i) & "]").text <> ""

. . .

Regards,

ScriptMan

Comment: I took from one of your previous posts on SCN

Comment: I took from one of your previous posts on SCN following and did piece it together. Ct = 0                                                                          Do Until Session.FindByID("wnd[1]/usr/tabs/TAB_STRIP/tabpNOSV/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3030/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE_E/txtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_[1, " & CStr(Ct) & "}".Text = ""                                                                                                               Ct = Ct + 1                                                                          Thank you a lot @ScriptMan, your help as I see is really great.